# Add custom option into shipping details of customer at checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, php, shipping

I am looking for tutorial for adding some new custom detail into shipping details. And then how to save that detail into database. I am working on magento framework and using php language. I  know magento handles the work of saving shipping details by itself. But i my not able to understand how it do this.
Help me for this case i really need to solve this asap and i am clueless.